# Facebook Go Live button does not connect a stream to Group Private or Closed

Tags: facebook, streaming, facebook-group

I have a Go Live button on my site.  It connects fine to Timelines and Fan Pages I manage but when I connect to a Group(Public or Closed) it fails.  Does anyone know why or found a solution around this?  This is the code that I am using.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('liveButton').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'live_broadcast',
    phase: 'create',
}, function(response) {
    if (!response.id) {
      alert('The broadcast connection to Facebook has been closed.');
      return;
    }
    //alert('stream url:' + response.secure_stream_url);
    FB.ui({
      display: 'popup',
      method: 'live_broadcast',
      phase: 'publish',
      broadcast_data: response,
    }, function(response) {
    //alert("video status: \n" + response.status);
    });
  });
};
</script>
```